# Can you write dapps in C based languages?

Tags: smart-contract, nft, token

Are there any good YouTube videos that are walk-through style for using a C-based language to write smart contracts, issue tokens and create NFTs?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you cannot write and deploy a smart contract in C on Cardano.

For native tokens (incl. NFTs), see the [developer portal](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/).

For writing smart contracts, you can use [Marlowe](https://alpha.marlowe.iohkdev.io) or the more powerful [Plutus](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/programming-languages/plutus/overview/).

Answer (score 3):

Not currently.

There is work being done on the [IELE VM](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/05/10/runtime-verification-iele-from-interoperability-to-universality/). In theory this will allow any language that can compile to [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) to be used to write smart contracts on Cardano. This includes C and C++, among other languages.